# access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes) | Mysql | NestJs

Tags: mysql, база-данных, backend, nestjs

Я делаю бэкенд. Использую NestJs и хочу подключить mysql базу данных.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule, 
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "*******",
      "password": "*******",
      "database": "*******",
      "entities": [],
      "synchronize": true
  }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Но у меня выводит следующую ошибку:

```
Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...
Error: Access denied for user 'root_*****'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Я в mysql не разбираюсь. База данных находиться уже на хостинге или как там (site.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php)

P.S У меня нет полного доступа к функциям phpMyAdmin базе данных (не знаю влияет ли это)

Comment: Проверяйте данные, которые указываете. Вам же MySQL пишет, что неверный пользователь или пароль. Возможно, Ваш хостер хранит БД отдельно, и подключение идет не по `localhost`. PhpMyAdmin ни на что не влияет, это интерфейс для управления базой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `localhost` поставил домен сайта `site.com`